# java logging/Log Server

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, logging, client-server

Say I have DemoServer project that only logs anything and I created another project say LogServer. So here's what I want to do; I will run both project simultaneously, as the DemoServer is running it will just keep on logging anything and in the LogServer project it should be able to access the logs that the DemoServer generates and save it to a new text file every 1 minute. Since this is the first time I'm doing this I find it hard to figure out how will the two project communicate? Can someone explain in detail how can i achieve this? Please also post links that might help me solve my problem.

Comment: Ready to use APIs may help instead of creating your own log servers

Comment: No I really need to learn how to create my own log server

Comment: Your real concern seems to be interprocess communication (probably as an exercise?) and logging doesn't have much to do with it. Try to focus on that in your question unless you want 10 answers mentioning various existing logging frameworks.

Comment: Yes I really don't have a problem with logging I just want to figure out how can the two application communicate. Actually I'm using log4j

Answer (score 1):

I'd go with a local socket which is quite straightforward to implement in Java and can be later used also when DemoServer and LogServer are on different machines.

Developing it should be quite easy:

- create your own `LogMessage` class
- create a simple client/server infrastructure by using TCP sockets, take a look [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/clientServer.html)
- wrap the socket streams by using `ObjectInputStream` and `ObjectOutputStream` to be able to use [serialization](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Programming/serialization/)
- just send logs by encapsulating them in messages from one process to the other and you are done

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you dig into [oVirt](http://www.ovirt.org) source code (you can git clone the source) and see what we do with the log collector application. 
There are many options to solve your problem -  
A. Have your application log into a shared storage (i.e - nfs share) - one that both it and the log server can access. A cron job will run a periodic script that will copy the files that were last accessed, let's say - one hour ago, into a folder, that the the log server can access. 
B. Use log4j and write your own Appender that will send the stuff you want log server to collect also to log server (via a file as suggested in section A, or via any other mean) - this way you will be able to contol on a category level basis what stuff the Log server can actually read